# How to connect pgadmin 4 to an external server?

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, pgadmin

I just created a server (droplets) in digital ocean, install postgresql, up there well, it works on the console. My problem is when I try to connect through pgadmin.

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "165.22.184.123" and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Look for information and modify the file
 `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`
where says `listen_addresses='localhost'`  by  `listen_addresses='*'`.

Also add a line to `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to the file `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`  and I still have the same problem. Do I have to do some additional configuration?

Comment: Are you using any sort of firewall on the digital ocean droplet?

Comment: listen_addresses should be '*' instead of 'localhost'. Post this did you restarted the system. This could be one reason